# Cannot install packages in Rstudio

Tags: r

I just installed R studio and I was trying to install rmarkdown. However, I got the error as below. I unchecked the box ''Tools -> Global Options -> Packages ->  Use secure download method for HTTP'' as someone suggested. No help. I tried other packages, I got the same error.
[image: Error]

Comment: I wouldn't uncheck that box. Is the computer connected to the internet? Can you access the https://cran.rstudio.com/ URL in your web browser? Are you behind a network firewall that might be blocking access? The error message seems to indicate that R cannot communicate with the server where all the packages are hosted.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, I can access the URL and the computer is connected to the internet.

Comment: What OS are you running? Do you have to use a proxy server to connect to the internet? does `download.file("https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES", "text.txt")` also fail? Maybe try running `chooseCRANmirror()` and choosing a different server to see if you can connect to another site. If you are on a network managed by an employer, perhaps you can ask an IT person to troubleshoot your network connectivity.

Comment: @MrFlick I am using Windows 10. Yes, all fail. Choosing other server gives me "Warning message: In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :   InternetOpenUrl failed: 'Y«ø'"

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the package and reinstall it using `dependencies = TRUE`:

```
remove.packages("rmarkdown")
  install.packages("rmarkdown", dependencies = TRUE)
  library(rmarkdown)
```

Output:

```
Warning message:
package ‘rmarkdown’ was built under R version 4.1.2
```

Comment: I got "Error in library(rmarkdown) : there is no package called ‘rmarkdown’"

Comment: @Nan Maybe first Restart R session and try again.

Comment: Tried lots of times and even reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was due to the newest version of the toolboxes include the names is under new package names. Go to the URL https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES and search for "rmarkdown". Find the package name and try to install that instead. It's like a .zip file that includes several packages to your library. Try install.packages("accucor"). It worked for me at least, and then try to install the rmarkdown package.